# Android load some data

Tags: android, exception

So i have a question, why my function `getIt()`  breaks at `httpGet` and gives `Exception`, in manifest I added `INTERNET` permission! I am not using AsyncTask, because me need to create a new class, and if i call AsyncTask with `get` it's blocking my UI

**Class.java**

```
public class loadMovies{
    public String getIt(){
        InputStream ips = null;
        JSONObject json = null;
        String get = "";
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://mysite/app/movies");
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            ips = response.getEntity().getContent();

            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ips));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while((line = buffer.readLine()) != null){
                builder.append(line+"\n");
            }
            json = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
            Log.d(TAG, json.toString());
        }
        catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }

        if(json != null){
            JSONArray array = json.optJSONObject("data").optJSONArray("movies");

            for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                JSONObject rss = array.optJSONObject(i);
                get += rss.optString("name")+"\n";
            }
        }
        return get;
    }       
}
```

Comment: COuld you add an error log/logcat? What kind of exception does it give?

Comment: 01-05 21:08:38.192: D/Afisha(29030): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if i call AsyncTask with get it's block my UI

because as doc says about [AsyncTask get ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) :

> Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves
>   its result.

to avoid block UI use `AsyncTask` without calling `get` method on UI thread and update UI when `doInBackground` execution complete in `onPostExecute` .

create your AsyncTask class as :

```
public class LongloadMovies extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            loadMovies loadmovobj =new loadMovies();
            String strresult=loadmovobj.getIt();
            return strresult;
      }      

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {     

           // Update your UI here          
      }

}
```

and execute AsyncTask as from UI thread :

```
new LongloadMovies().execute("");
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your application crashes on Android versions 3.0 and above, is because HoneyComb, Ice Cream Sandwich and JellyBean are much stricter about abuse against the UI Thread. For example, when an Android device running HoneyComb or above detects a network access on the UI thread, a NetworkOnMainThreadException will be thrown:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(673): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.ExampleActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

The explanation as to why this occurs is well documented on the Android developer's site:

```
A NetworkOnMainThreadException is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread. This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily discouraged.
```

Some examples of other operations that ICS and HoneyComb won't allow you to perform on the UI thread are:

1. Opening a Socket connection (i.e. new Socket()).
2. HTTP requests (i.e. HTTPClient and HTTPUrlConnection).
3. Attempting to connect to a remote MySQL database.
4. Downloading a file (i.e. Downloader.downloadFile()).

If you are attempting to perform any of these operations on the UI thread, you must wrap them in a worker thread. The easiest way to do this is to use of an AsyncTask, which allows you to perform asynchronous work on your user interface. An AsyncTask will perform the blocking operations in a worker thread and will publish the results on the UI thread, without requiring you to handle threads and/or handlers yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have network operations on main ui thread. You need to do this in another thread or async task. [Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html) is tut that talks about this